# ¿Cómo es el proceso de implementación de una cola con arreglo?

Tags: c++, c

Sé lo que es una **cola** y lo que es un **arreglo**, pero no entiendo la unión de ambos, necesito que me expliquen dicho proceso con ejemplos cotidianos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con una simple imagen se aclara todo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La relación con un *arreglo* es simple:

- #### Encolar

Colocar un nuevo elemento **al final** del arreglo.

- #### Desencolar

  Obtener el **primer** elemento del arreglo.

Dependiendo de la implementación que uses, este último paso puede implicar **mover** todos los elementos del arreglo **1 posición** *hacia abajo*.

- #### Tamaño de la cola

Número de elementos *máximos* que caben en el arreglo.

- #### Elementos en la cola

Número de elementos **ocupados** en el arreglo. El resto serán *huecos libres*.

- #### Ejemplos de la vida diaria

Los que quieras, cualquier **cola** o *fila de espera* te sirve: fila en las cajas, fila para entrar al autobus ... cualquier espera en el que el primero *abandona* la cola y los demás *avanzan una posición*. Los *nuevos* que van llegando se colocan *al final*.

Página de la [Wikipedia sobre *colas*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cola_(inform%C3%A1tica)), de donde obtuve la imagen.

Answer (score 0):

Tanto en C como en C++ los objetos simples se pueden crear en el *stack* (la pila) o en el *heap* (memoria dinámica).

En el primer caso los objetos los estaremos usando por valor, que es el caso típico que uno encuentra al aprender a programar:

```
int main()
{
  int var = 1; // Variable declarada en la pila
  printf("%d",var);
}
```

El problema lo encontramos al usar tipos compuestos (listas, vectores, matrices)... Ninguno de los dos lenguajes dispone de un tipo nativo para gestionar este tipo de objetos y en su lugar se recurre a los punteros:

```
int main()
{
  int lista[10]; // Aunque no lo parezca esto es un puntero

  int* ptr = lista; // Y la prueba está en que aquí no hay error

  for( int i=0; i<10; i++)
    *ptr = i;

  for( int i=0; i<10; i++)
    printf("%d\n", lista[i]);
}
```

**NOTA:** No voy a entrar en detalles sobre cómo gestionan C o C++ el uso de arreglos de tamaño fijo... si hay dudas al respecto es preferible abrir una nueva pregunta.

El caso es que una cola suele ser, básicamente, una lista no ordenada de elementos y por lo que acabamos de ver, la única forma de gestionar una lista es mediante arreglos ya que el lenguaje no dispone de un tipo nativo específico para este menester.

Un ejemplo muy sencillo de cola (basada en un buffer circular) podría ser entonces :

```
int cola[10]; // arreglo de 10 elementos
int push;
int pop;

void Inicializar()
{
  push = 0;
  pop = -1;
}

void Push(int numero)
{
  if( push != pop ) // Cola llena
    cola[push] = numero;

  if( pop == -1 )
    pop = push; // Ya hay elementos a extraer de la cola

  push = (push+1)%10;
}

int Pop()
{
  int toReturn = -1; // Valor a devolver si la cola está vacía

  if( pop != -1 )
  {
    toReturn = cola[pop];

    pop = (pop+1)%10;

    if( pop == push )
      pop = -1; // Si hemos extraido el último indicamos que está vacía
  }

  return toReturn; 
}
```

Y una prueba de uso:

```
int main()
{
  Inicializar();
  Push(2);
  Push(4);

  printf("%d\n",Pop()); // 2
  printf("%d\n",Pop()); // 4
  printf("%d\n",Pop()); // -1
}
```